# Is there a way to determine the source device of a KeyboardEvent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard

This is for a Chrome extension where I'd like to distinguish between a [KeyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) coming from the regular keyboard vs. an additional external numpad.

Something like getting the USB vendor and product ID per key press would be ideal, but any bit that makes the two events look different would work.

Thanks!

Comment: If the `KeyboardEvent` object has a property `location === 3`, this would indicate that the input came from a num pad (real or virtual) rather than the main part of the keyboard. It is not what you are looking for exactly but might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! Unfortunately, in this case, events from either keyboard report `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD (0x00)` for the `location` property.